# Compare all array elements in js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

Here is a demo of the current code: http://mobilocloud.com/schedule/

I have one js object that contains multiple arrays, each array has two time hashes (one start time and one end time / I've got them using `getTime()`). I want to compare all of the arrays contained in the object to check for all of the intersections between time ranges. I've got the script working but it only compares two arrays at a time (in the end I get groups of two overlapped events). I want to get groups of all overlapped events, not only by two.

Here is the actual code:

```
function _DetectOverlapedEvents(column) {
    events;
    groups;
    sgroups;
    todeoverlap[column] = new Array();
    groups[column] = new Array();
    sgroups[column] = new Array();
    var $curid=0;
    var $curevent= new Array();
    if(events[column].length > 1){
        $(events[column]).each(function(key, $secondevent) {
            //alert("Comparing : " + $curevent["name"] + " and " + $secondevent["name"] + "\n" + $curevent["starthash"] + "<" +$secondevent["endhash"] + " = " + ($curevent["starthash"] < $secondevent["endhash"]) + "\n&&\n" + $curevent["endhash"] + ">" + $secondevent["starthash"] + " = " + ($curevent["endhash"] > $secondevent["starthash"]));
            if($curevent.length<2) {
                $curevent=$secondevent;
            } else if(($curevent["starthash"] < $secondevent["endhash"]) && ($curevent["endhash"] > $secondevent["starthash"])) {
                //alert("added " + $curevent["name"] + " and " + $secondevent["name"]);
                toextend = {left: $curevent, right: $secondevent};
                groups[column].push(toextend);
                sgroups[column].push($curevent, $secondevent);
                //console.log("groups: " + JSON.stringify(groups[column]));
                $curid++;
            }
            $curevent = $secondevent;
        });
    }
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(groups));
}
```

[image]

Comment: what's the expected output format? what have you tried? what didn't work?

Comment: `if(events[column].length > 1){` - in this context, `events` is undefined and is definitely not an array.